# ¿Como traducir TODO el programa en python?

Tags: python

espero que no moleste; pero necesito que alguien me ayude para poder traducir todo mi programa de Python para poder ponerlo en ingles.
He estado probando este codigo pero no funciona y me tira error...

```
from translate import Translator
    
    trad = Translator(
        from_lang="es",
        to_lang="en",
        text="Hola, soy un usuario de la aplicacion de traduccion",
    )
    txt = input("Ingrese un texto: ")
    res = trad.translate(txt)
    print (res)
```

Ya he probado a poner `pip install translate` en la **Terminal** pero este me sigue dando error de `reportMissingImports`
Muchas Gracias si alguien me responde :D

Espero que tengan un buen dia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes descargarte el source y:

```
python setup.py install
```

Luego, en la línea de comando:

```
$ translate-cli -t es "This is a pen."
```

Para otras opciones:

```
$ translate-cli --help
```

También lo puedes usar como módulo en Python:

```
In [1]: from translate import Translator
In [2]: translator= Translator(to_lang="es")
In [3]: translation = translator.translate("This is a pen.")
Out [3]: Esto es un bolígrafo
```